# Solve $\frac{\theta}{\arcsin\left[\cos(\theta)\right]}=\frac{\pi}{4}$

Tags: trigonometry

I have an integral I'm working on and upon making a substitution, I need to figure out if there is an analytic solution to the following equation:

$$\frac{\theta}{\arcsin\left[\cos(\theta)\right]}=\frac{\pi}{4}$$

The solution is approximately $0.690995$

Comment: Would you mind sharing the integral?

Comment: @Tolaso It's kind of a messed up one...Let $a_{n}(x)=\arcsin\Big[\cos(x\cdot a_{n-1}(x))\Big]$ with $a_{1}(x)=\arcsin\Big[\cos(x)\Big]$...determine $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}a_{n}(x)\mathrm dx$$

Comment: @BrianConstantinescu Using dominated convergence I get that the integral converges to $\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{1}{x+1}\:dx$. Where does your substitution come from?

Comment: @NinadMunshi Ah Interesting! I arrived to something more complicated but gives the same solution...Let $p(\pi)=\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{2\pi}{\pi +4}$, then the limit integral is equivalent to $$p(\pi)+\int_{0}^{p(\pi)}\frac{x}{\arcsin(\cos(x))}\mathrm dx$$

Comment: I see! if you want, you can post the integral as a separate question and I'd be more than happy to write up the other way of doing the problem, otherwise cheers!

Comment: I would be interested to see the dominated convergence approach...now because of Covid-19 my entire city is in lockdown so I've been creating integrals in my head and trying to solve them. The latest batch have been these funky limit integrals because it's really hard to devise some that actually work haha

Comment: @NinadMunshi  I've asked the question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3596814/evaluating-integrals-of-infinitely-concatenated-functions-viz-dominated-converg

Answer (score 5):

Use the identity

$$\arcsin x + \arccos x = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

where we get that

$$\frac{\theta}{\arcsin(\cos\theta)} = \frac{\theta}{\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta} = \frac{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta} - 1 = \frac{\pi}{4}$$

$$\implies \theta = \frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{2\pi}{\pi+4}$$

if $\theta \in [0,\pi]$

Comment: cheers! I should really go back to Wiki's list of trig identities and get to memorizing again.

Comment: Equivalently, $\theta=\frac{\pi^2}{2(\pi+4)}$.

Comment: @BrianConstantinescu thank you but remembering all of them is not necessary! There are only a few that show up quite frequently in integrals, this being one of them.

Comment: @BrianConstantinescu: There's actually an intuitive way to remember the formula. Draw a right triangle with three angles: $\phi=\arcsin(x), \theta=\arccos(x),$ and $\pi/2$. Since opposite over hypothenuse (with respect to $\phi$) is $x$, you can label the hypothenuse to be $1$ and the leg opposite from $\phi$ is x. From this diagram, you notice that $\theta=\arccos(x)$ produces the same diagram. Therefore, this triangle is legitimate. Since a triangle's angles sum to $\pi$ radians and the other angle is $\pi/2$, it follows that $\phi + \theta=\pi/2$.

Comment: @zugzug I see! That's a very neat construction :D thanks

Comment: @J.G. thanks for mentioning the an equivalent solution! A second answer to this post arrives to that same solution :D

Answer (score 1):

$\arcsin(\cos \theta)=\pi/2-\theta$ which gives $$\frac {\theta}{\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta}=\frac{\pi}{4}$$ $$\theta=\frac{\pi^2}{8}-\frac{\pi \theta}{4}$$ 
$$\theta \frac{\pi+4}{4}=\frac{\pi^2}{8}$$ $$\theta=\frac{\pi^2}{2(\pi+4)}$$

Comment: Neat approach! I appreciate it :D